# Trouble with fwrite after fseek - C (binary)

Tags: c, binary

Any idea why the following code isn't working?

My struct:

```
struct Records
{
    int Number;
    char Name[20];
    float Salary;
};
```

Code in main:

```
FILE * binaryfile;
binaryfile = fopen("binaryfile.dat","r+b");

struct Records MyRecords;

printf("Name: \n");
gets(MyRecords.Name);

printf("Yearly Salary: \n");
scanf("%f%*c",&MyRecords.Salary);

fseek(binaryfile,2L*sizeof(struct Records),SEEK_SET);

fread(&MyRecords.Number, sizeof(MyRecords.Number), 1, binaryfile);
fwrite(&MyRecords.Name, sizeof(MyRecords.Name), 1, binaryfile);
fwrite(&MyRecords.Salary, sizeof(MyRecords.Salary), 1, binaryfile);
```

I missed the lesson for binary so my understanding of this is very shaky, but this is what i'm trying to do:

With fseek, I'm going to the beginning of the 3rd record, which is "3,Random Name,50.00".

Then I'm reading the 3 into MyRecords.Number (i've tested up to this point). Then when the pointer is on name, I'm attempting to overwrite it and the salary with new ones.

Yet somehow it doesn't work. I've tried changing the file Opening to stuff like ab+, wb+, rb+, rb, with no success.

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work," what exactly do you mean? Do you get a compilation error, or does it throw an exception, or does it simply not work the way you want it to?

Comment: How does it not work ? What happens ? What should happen ? Are you certain sizeof(struct Records) is the size you need to jump back&forth(this depends on how you write the records, keep in mind that the sum of the size of all struct members might not be the same size as the whole struct). Also, all these functions(scanf/fseek/fwrite ... ) return error/success codes. You should check these, otherwise how would you know when something breaks ?

Comment: No errors at all. It's reading fine, but it's not writing properly. With w+b the whole file gets overwritten with 2 empty values, with ab/rb nothing gets written.

Comment: I'm sure I got to the right place as I tested that fread value after the fseek, and it came out to be 3 - correct.
I need to overwrite AFTER that 3, the next two variables - a string then a float.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO, you always should use a complete structure in your code: read it (i.e. fread(&MyRecords, sizeof(MyRecord)...) ), change the elements, fseek again at the same place and fwrite the whole structure. The way you are doing, you may experience any sort of problems with data alignment.

Comment: I changed it like you said and the modified code worked perfectly; sweet :))

Answer (score 0):

Like Chris said, you need to be more specific about what isn't working. At a casual glance your code seems correct. Have you verified that binaryfile.dat indeed exists in the folder from where you're running the program, and that it's formatted is it should be?

Answer (score 0):

Try dropping the `&` from:

```
fwrite(&MyRecords.Name, sizeof(MyRecords.Name), 1, binaryfile);
       ^
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use "r+b" as using "w+b" will erase the file (as you have observed) and either "ab" or "rb" will not allow writing to the file - you need the "+" in there too.